# How to post the activity made by user on the website to his/her facebook account wall?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm working first time on such kind of task, so bit unware of such things. 
  Basically I've a website developed in PHP. Now when user visits my website I want to provide the facility of posting activities performed by the user on the website to his/her wall as post. 
  For that I referred one website `http://www.meritnation.com`. I want somewhat similar facebook functionality like the one this site has. 
  I also did R & D on how to achieve this. During R & D I came to know about Facebook Platform (`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/`). I gone through it but couldn't get the idea of how to actually achieve this. 
  Can anyone help me out by explaining how to achieve this in simple language? 
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably looking for this [Getting Started With Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

The link below, on Facebook's developer website, has very good examples on how to post to the user's wall. I've found them very helpful.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/